# How to embed file content into body of the email using mail command?

Tags: email

It must be *soooo* simple, but all of the examples that I found after a few hours of googling *don't* work, as the mail is always *attached* to the file instead of writing it *into* the body. 
I don't want to send empty messages either, but want to send mail only when I have output from the script. Here is my command:

```
$script_file  > /tmp/output.log ; mail -E -s "Output subject" "my@emailaddress"  < /tmp/output.log ; rm -f /tmp/output.log
```

Would it be possible to change this command to force the mail to embed the content of the `output.log` file?

My system is CentOS.

Many thanks!

Comment: Skip the whole output file completely and do `$script_file  | mail -E -s "Output subject" "my@emailaddress"`

Comment: Thanks, but your example is just send an email and doesn't embed my file into the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `mutt` to do that, like this. Be aware of argument order, do not place recipient after `-a`

`mutt joe@example.com -s "Mail subject" -a /file/to/attach < /file/with/mail/body`

Comment: Thanks Dan, it's almost perfect as the content of the file is already in the email body! Is it possible to have the same result but without attaching the same file?

Comment: This is working:  mutt  -s "Mail subject" joe@example.com < /file/with/mail/body but I still got the empty email messages when the output file is blank.

Comment: Wrap it around an empty file test, like `if -s /mail/body; then mutt bla bla; fi`

Answer (score 0):

You can use cat  and pipe it to redirect the output to mail.

`$script_file  > /tmp/output.log ; cat /tmp/output.log | mail -s "Output subject" "my@emailaddress"   ; rm -f /tmp/output.log`

(I'm not sure there is -E though so I removed it)

Comment: Thanks, I've found this solution though and just tried again but it still attached the file :(

Comment: As mutt is working for you it seems to be MIME issue. You need to define mime type  say `text/plain`  add `set content_type=text/plain`
`mutt -e set content_type=text/plain joe@example.com -s "Mail subject" -a /file/to/attach < /file/with/mail/body`   while sending email out it always checks the MIME type and it seems its not able to figure out what MIME type to use by default for the script output file and its sending empty attachments.